# How to check the file input to know if it's empty in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to check whether the user has actually chosen a file before pressing on upload or not, if so then check if the file is bigger than 4 MB. If the user has pressed on upload without choosing a file then a message should be sent telling them to go back and choose a file. But this code doesn't seem to work.

```html
<div id="postUpload-wrapper">
  <form id="uploadpost-form" action="/uploadpost" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="postname" placeholder="Title" name="postname">
    <br>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="image">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id "uploadpost-btn" value="Upload" name="uploadpost">
  </form>
</div>
```

```
//UPLOAD A POST

router.post('/uploadpost', upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
var errors = "";

if(req.body.postname === ""){
    errors += "Write a title";
    res.send(errors);
    return false;
}

//problem here
if(req.file.size === 0){
    errors += "You need to choose a file";
    res.send(errors);
    return false;
}else{
    if(req.file.size > 4000000){
        errors += "Files can only be up to 4 MB in size";
        res.send(errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not check this on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `input type="submit"` element property `disabled` to `"true"` , use `onchange` event of `input type="file"` element to check if user selected file at `FileList` object , set `type="submit"` element to `disabled="true"` , `disabled="false"` if `file.size` greater than `4000000` bytes . If file not selected , file size over `4000000` bytes submit button set to disabled

```js
var input = document.getElementById("fileupload");
input.onchange = function() {
  var file = this.files, submit = this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
  if (file.length > 0) {
    if (file[0].size >= 4000000) {
      submit.disabled = true;
      alert("file size limit")
    } else {
      submit.disabled = false;
      console.log(this.files)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="postUpload-wrapper">
  <form id="uploadpost-form" action="/uploadpost" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="postname" placeholder="Title" name="postname">
    <br>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="image">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="uploadpost-btn" value="Upload" name="uploadpost" disabled="true">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is really great albeit it doesn't really work :D but it gave me an idea. First of, instead of the `if(file > 0)` block of code which is supposed to check the size. I found it better to check for the length, using  `elementID.files.length`. If it is 0 then no file has been chosen, if 1 then a file has already been chosen. Second, to check for the size in the first place one needs to write `elementID.files[0].size` to get the size in bytes. So in my code I first checked the length. If it's 0 then submit.disabled stays true, if not then I check the size and do what is left to be done.

Comment: @TonyLee Yes, missed including `.length` , `[0].size` at post ; updated

Comment: It is not an answer to a question, besides you should never rely only on client side code doing validation alone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check this on the client side before allowing the file to be uploaded.

```
if(document.getElementById("uploadpost-btn").value != "") {
   // you have a file
}
```

You can later check on the server-side. If `req.body` has any data then there was a file uploaded.